# Как организовать цикл чтения файла, если регистр СХ занят адресом памяти?

Tags: алгоритм, циклы, ассемблер

Возник вопрос по поводу системных прерываний и циклов в `asm`. Допустим, у меня есть текстовый файл, размер которого мне неизвестен. Там может быть любое количество символов. Как прочесть его полностью?

Я думаю, нужно выделить какой-то фиксированный буффер (к примеру, 20 "слов") и в цикле каждую итерацию перемещать указатель на файл:

Но как организовать цикл если `ecx`, а соответственно и `cx` будет занят адрисом, куда нужно будет читать данные, а соответственно нельзя будет использовать этот регистр в качестве счетчика для цикла?

Comment: Ну цикл ведь не обязательно `loop`. Храните счетчик хоть в памяти...

Comment: ... да даже вульгарного push/pop никто не отменял.

Comment: `cmp геристр,регистр` - устанавливает все флаги сравнения.